# Get value of interface{ } without having access to type

Tags: go, types, reflection, type-assertion

How can I get the value of `x` as `[]interface{}` ?

```
func main() {

    var x interface{} = SomeFunc()
    
    fmt.Println(x) // this prints [1 2].

    val := x.([]interface{}) // this will not work because '[]interface{}' is different type than 'a'

}

func SomeFunc() interface{} {
    // some type I dont have access to
    type a []interface{}

    var someArray a = make([]interface{}, 0)
    someArray = append(someArray, 1)
    someArray = append(someArray, 2)
    return someArray
}
```

Comment: Why not return `[]interface{}` from `SomeFunc()` directly?

Comment: I am generating source code dynamically  with code and its a pain to import so many different packages. It is hard to make it compile when its being automatically being generated. I already know most of the value types. It will be nice if I could use those values.

Comment: I guess I will just import the needed packages. I though it was going to be easier to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Type asserting](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) a *concrete* type works only for the exact  ([identical](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity)) concrete type stored in an interface value, you can't type assert "similar" types (e.g. types having the same underlying type).

In your case what you want is get a value that is convertible to a known type (e.g. a value of type `a` convertible to a value of type `[]interface{}`). As said above, this is not possible with type assertion.

The easiest is to import the package that holds the definition of the concrete type (and type assert a value of that type). If it's not exported or not accessible, your only option is using reflection. You may use [`Value.Convert()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Convert) to convert a value to a value of another type, a value of a type you *can* type assert. To check if the value is actually convertible, you may use [`Value.CanConvert()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.CanConvert).

```
y := reflect.ValueOf(x).Convert(reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{})).Interface()

val := y.([]interface{})
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", val, val)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/d2_cyGk9GZN)):

```
[1 2]
[]interface {} [1 2]
```